Change XML Value with Groovy in SAP CPI
I want to change the node "firstname" in my XML. I wrote a groovy script for it, but it doesn't do anything. When I log the line, were I set firstname.value, I get the right result. But somehow it doesn't save the changes.
This is my Code:
def Message FirstName2Fullname(Message message) {
    
    def fullName = message.getProperty("ContactName")

    Reader reader = message.getBody(Reader)
    def body = new XmlParser().parse(reader)


        body.properties.firstname.value[0] = fullName


    String modifiedXmlString = XmlUtil.serialize(body)

    message.setBody(modifiedXmlString)
    
    return message

}

Please help
I tried Groovy IDE, searched the internet but no success.
